# CloudRun database connection dissapearing?

Tags: google-cloud-run

some days ago I was able to set up one of my apps to be connected to one of my database instances from the google cloud run service configuration form. However lately I notice two things:

1. I'm no longer able to select the database instance my service is/will be connected to.
2. On a service that is connected using this method I no longer see the database connection name. at the bottom on the details panel.

Is this a symptom that the database connections feature will disappear from the Google CloudRun settings?.

Comment: This sort of question should go directly to Google through Cloud Run support.  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/support

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @DougStevenson. You mean paid support? or other channel different than this one ?

Comment: Hello, Hey is the database you're trying to connect managed by google, like Cloud SQL? If this is the case, the page says it is in beta and that it could change over the time, also the support is limited on this cases, but it could be the better way to go with.

Comment: Yes. It is a google managed database (CloudSQL). Right, since its in beta, i wonder if this feature will continue there or it's going to go away. (feature to connect your CloudRun services with CloudSql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a useful case to use the Cloud SDK to confirm your Cloud Run service is able to communicate with Cloud SQL. This will help confirm if you have a UI problem or something deeper. This is especially important given the documentation states that the Console instructions are not available yet.

Cloud Run supports Cloud SQL via gcloud management using a [special flag to associate a Cloud SQL instance with an individual service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connect-cloudsql).

Once this is done, the Cloud SQL instance will be available to the Cloud Run service until it is explicitly removed.

You can verify this connection is in place by looking at the service description:

```
gcloud beta run services describe [SERVICE-NAME]
```

in the response, you should see the property **run.googleapis.com/cloudsql-instances** inside `spec.runLatest.configuration.revisionTemplate.metadata.annotations`.

As long as that annotation is present and contains your Cloud SQL instance connection name, your service should be able to connect to the SQL instance as documented (assuming your service has authorization to connect to the Cloud SQL instance)

Comment: Thanks @Grayside for the answer. This is very helpful for me, i did not consider the CLI to associate the SQL instance.